# How to get date range on oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with column say

```
start_date   |end_date
21-NOV-2014  |  23-DEC-2014
01-JAN-2015  |   null
01-JUNE-2014 | 03-MAR-2015
01-DEC-2014  | 29-DEC-2014
```

if i give 01-DEC-2014 it has to pick dates which are overlapping in the date range.
In this case it hase to pick 1,3,4th record.
But if i give 04-JAN-2015 it should pick all records.

Comment: `WHERE YOUR_DATE_VALUE BETWEEN START_DATE AND NVL(END_DATE,YOUR_DATE_VALUE) ` - Hope this works?

Comment: What have you tried? This question seems to come back every single day... is it possible you haven't found a single answer to help you on this?

Comment: why would 04-JAN-2015 pick the first or last record? those end dates are prior to 04-JAN-2015.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE YOUR_DATE_VALUE BETWEEN START_DATE AND NVL(END_DATE,YOUR_DATE_VALUE)
```

The above should work! Defaulting end date as your date inputitself, in case of null (`NVL()`)!

Comment: how to get for null values?

Comment: @GaneshHegde for null values you mean?